# Как реализовать постепенное растворение фона?

Tags: java, android

Я сделал программу наподобие хаотичного движения газов, и мне нужно чтобы при запуске они растворялись (увеличивали свою прозрачность). У меня все вышло, только после их растворения они снова становятся непрозрачными и процесс повторяется. Попробовал ограничить условием в цикле перебора шариков`(alpha[i]<=0) { break}`, но выходит что при запуске все уже растворилось и анимации нету. Что не так?

```
package com.example.android19anim1;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.view.View;

public class MyDraw extends View {
    static int n = 15;
    static boolean started;
    int[] x = new int[n];
    int[] y = new int[n];
    int[] vx = new int[n];
    int[] vy = new int[n];
    int[] color1 = new int[n];
    int[] color2 = new int[n];
    int[] color3 = new int[n];
    static int[] alpha=new int [n];

    int random(int min, int max) {
        return (int) (min + Math.random() * (max + 1));
    }

    void fillArrayRandom(int[] a, int min, int max) {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            a[i] = random(min, max);
        }
    }

    void makeBalls() {
        fillArrayRandom(x, 0, this.getWidth());
        fillArrayRandom(y, 0, this.getHeight());
        fillArrayRandom(vx, -10, 50);
        fillArrayRandom(vy, -10, 50);
        fillArrayRandom(color1, 0, 255);
        fillArrayRandom(color2, 0, 255);
        fillArrayRandom(color3, 0, 255);
    }

    void moveBalls() {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if ((x[i] < 0) || (x[i] > this.getWidth())) {
                vx[i] = -vx[i];
            }
            if ((y[i] < 0) || (y[i] > this.getHeight())) {
                vy[i] = -vy[i];
            }
            x[i] += vx[i];
            y[i] += vy[i];
            alpha[i]-=1;
            if(alpha[i]<=0) {
                break;
            }
            }
        }


    public MyDraw(Context context) {
        super(context);
        MyTimer timer = new MyTimer();
        timer.start();
    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        if (!started) {
            makeBalls();
            started = true;
        }
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            canvas.drawCircle(x[i], y[i], 20, paint);
            paint.setColor(Color.argb(alpha[i],color1[i], color2[i], color3[i]));
        }

    }

    void nextFrame() {
        moveBalls();
        invalidate();
    }

    // public static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    //
    // public static void main(String[] args) {
    // System.out.println("Введите колличество шариков");
    // n = scan.nextInt();
    // }

    class MyTimer extends CountDownTimer {

        MyTimer() {
            super(1000000, 100);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            nextFrame();

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте callback, который сделает view невидимым по окончанию анимации или вообще удалит view из viewGroup.
callback:

```
yourView.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener()...
```